# Post date has some offset

Tags: jekyll

In my post I defined

```
---
title:  "Writing a manual test"
date:   2015-09-18 22:40:58
---
```

but doing `jekyll serve` it is rendered as

[image: Jekyll date shown]

I believe this has to do with the time offset of my PC, which is UTC-2:00 at the moment.

How can I tell Jekyll to use the date of the post "as is"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the time of all posts to UTC, add the line

```
timezone: UTC
```

to `_config.yml`.